# Why the DAY() function can be executed during query, but an error is reported when inserting

Tags: mysql

MySQL version is 8.0.23

Create table and insert data

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1 (c1 varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE test2 (c1 varchar(10));

INSERT INTO test1 SELECT '20210818';
INSERT INTO test1 SELECT '20210819';
INSERT INTO test1 SELECT '20210832';
```

When I use the DAY() function to check the date of test1, the sql is executed successfully

```sql
mysql> SELECT IF(DAY(c1) IS NULL ,'20210101',c1) FROM test1;
+------------------------------------+
| IF(DAY(c1) IS NULL ,'20210101',c1) |
+------------------------------------+
| 20210818                           |
| 20210819                           |
| 20210101                           |
+------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

But when I insert the query result into the test2 table, sql reports an error

```sql
mysql> INSERT INTO test2 SELECT IF(DAY(c1) IS NULL ,'20210101',c1) FROM test1;
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '20210832'
```

Why the DAY() function can be executed during query, but an error is reported when inserting?

Comment: i have question why you would need to save date as string in the first place ?
and if your use case need that then you need to verify that it valid date before saving them as string in the first place or i am missing something

Comment: @justsomeone Data is provided by other systems，I need to verify the data

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all:

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '20210832'

One (or more) of your records have the text value `'20210832'`, which is not a valid date, as there is no such thing as August 32nd as a date.  You should fix your source data and then try again.  Note that in general it is always best to store dates in proper date columns, rather than as text, for reasons such as the error you are currently seeing.

Comment: Thank for you answer,i know the value '20210832' cause the error,but why the sql is executed successfully during query

Comment: @Hedwig In this case, maybe you should check the other answer.  MySQL has various server modes, some of which are lax to errors such as this one.  The best long term fix, though, is to scrub your date strings/data outside of MySQL _before_ you load it into a table.  Dealing with it once it is in the table can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The sql_mode STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, intended to give an error when the value you try to store is different than the value that actually gets stored, has the unfortunate side effect of making any date parsing that normally produces a warning produce an error instead.  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47b641983752e606f6606dcb2bc12898)

You can disable it for your session with:

```
set session sql_mode=replace(@@sql_mode,'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','');
```

Comment: The best corrective course of action here is not to mess around with server modes, but rather to fix the date data at its source.

Comment: @ysth Thank for you answer,I am a little confused about ‘the value you try to store is different than the value that actually gets stored’,what does it mean,what is 'try to store' and 'actually gets stored' in this example,is '20210832' and '20210101'?

Comment: @Hedwig for example, if you try to store 10000000000 into an int column, or 'ab' into a char(1) column; STRICT_TRANS_TABLES detemines whether that is an error or a warning (with the value truncated)

Comment: what I'm saying is mysql implemented this feature in a broken way, where it changes warnings to errors even when it wouldn't have affected what actually gets stored

Comment: @ysth in my example,Illegal values are converted to '20210101', why is there still an error?

Comment: because mysql implemented the feature in a buggy way, turning every such warning into an error even if it had no effect on what would actually be inserted (but only in data modification statements, not in select)